# {"error":"Not Found"} when I make a call for my Coinbase address

Tags: bitcoin, coinbase-api

I'm trying to get information about my Coinbase wallet address (copied from the "My Wallet Bitcoin Address" section of my Coinbase profile) through the Toshi API through the following rest call:

```
https://bitcoin.toshi.io/api/v0/addresses/{my_address}
```

But I'm getting the following error

```
{"error":"Not Found"}
```

Can anyone explain why this is?

Comment: Please re-ask this question on bitcoin.stackexchange.com

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because belongs to bitcoin.stackexchange

Comment: How is this different from any other Web Service question? Also the bit coin stack exchange is not explicitly development oriented. This is where the Coinbase developer page links to and there are currently 47 questions using the coinbase tag.

Comment: You will get more, better, eyeballs there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Toshi will return a 404 for addresses that don't have any transactions which explains this. If you send something to the address, it will show up.

Comment: This account sent money last week but has not received no money. Should I expect to it so show the transaction where it sent the money?